# mysql query select * from table where image!='' order by date and with different upload user

Tags: mysql

I want to make some mysql query, query out 5 image order by date, but from 5 different upload user.

mysql datatable Structure: `id, user_id, image, text, date`

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE image!=''
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

But this `GROUP BY` always cause get the `user_id` earlier upload image then make a `ORDER BY date DESC`, I need the fresh 5 images which uploaded by 5 differents users. Maybe should use some `UNION`, ask for a help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INNER JOIN with MAX

```
SELECT 
  mytable.* 
FROM
  mytable 
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(id) AS ID, id FROM mytable GROUP BY user_id) AS m 
    ON m.id = mytable.id 
WHERE image != '' 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY DATE DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

This will fetch the max(latest) id  and integrate it to the outer select

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE image!=''
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING date=max(date)
LIMIT 5
```

Not sure about `mysql` but this works in `sybase`.

Comment: thanks for this solution, but this will have another problem, your code would first `GROUP BY user_id` which user_id first insert into mytable, then do these 4 users' image stuff. but i need some effection like get all the newest images first, then group by users(remove duplicate user_id). thanks.